# 301 redirect using htacess not working in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all pages to a new homepage in another domain. I use htacess file. The site is a Wordpress site. I have taken my htacess file from homepage.

So my goal is to redirect any pages to [www.example.com.au](http://www.example.com.au)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\.au\/" [R=301,L]
```

But, the problem is, it does not change the url [www.oldsite.com.au/hello](http://www.oldsite.com.au/hello) only the home page is in affect.

Any solution to this? Could it be that it is the problem with the server or wordpress?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$` is not doing anything, remove it. Just have `RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com.au/ [R=301,L]` to redirect to new website

Comment: What do you think `^/?$` is doing? ([Regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html))

Comment: Hi @anubhava , I have written RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com.au/ [R=301,L] , but the same thing happen. It only redirects the home page. I want every single page in that website to go to example.com.au

Comment: Did you clear browser cache?